# Running a method on a runtime-declared class implementing an interface?

Tags: c#, .net

So I have an interface, IFormLogger, which contains a method "logData". I have a class which contains this interface and the methods of the interface. My logger, which is designed to be non-dependent on any other classes, has an object, "formOut", which stores a "new class()" which is declared in the other program.

When trying to compile, I get an "'object' does not contain a definition for 'logData', which is understandable."

How do I tell the compiler that the object it will be using has this interface and the method assosciated with it?

Code:

```
class logger
{
    public enum logOutput { CONSOLE, WINFORM, FILE };
    public enum logLevel { INFO, FINE, WARN, ERR };

    logOutput output;
    object formOut;

public logger(logOutput outputType, object outputForm)
    {
        this.output = outputType;
        if (!(outputForm is IFormLogger))
            throw new ArgumentException();
        else
            this.formOut = outputForm;
    }
public void log(string msg)
    {
        string toLog = String.Format("[{0}][INFO] {1}\n", getTime(), msg);
        if (output == logOutput.WINFORM)
        {
            formOut.logData(toLog);
        }
    }

interface IFormLogger
{
    void logData(string data);
}
```

In my program.cs file, where the logger is being constructed (cLoggerTest is the name of the form which implements IFormLogger):

```
logger l = new logger(logger.logOutput.WINFORM, new cLoggerTest());
```

Comment: Public member names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: @SLaks okay, thanks, i'm a self-taught programmer so my formatting isn't always up to par with how it should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the field and parameter as `IFormLogger`, not `object`.
The compiler will then let you use all members in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

First, change the `object formOut` field to `IFormLogger formOut` and then assign it if/when the argument is of the correct type.

Replace this:

```
if (!(outputForm is IFormLogger))
    throw new ArgumentException();
else
    this.formOut = outputForm;
```

with this:

```
this.formOut = outputForm as IFormLogger;
if (this.formOut == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(/*something useful*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to declare *formOut* as an *IFormLogger* instead of an *object*.
Since you are already checking for that type in your code, it will not add any new dependency.